# Using Magento as a standard website at first?

Tags: php, html, magento, responsive-design, e-commerce

I have an e-commerce web project for a convience store. I have been researching for a good e-commerce CMS and am pretty convinced that Magento is a good one and i'll be probably considering it.

The project is to be divided into two phases where first the client needs a simple website with forms to gather delivery information and careers forms, along with data reprensentstion in a good UI such as accordion and specific html5 designs. The website shall be responsive.

The other phase (after few months) will be the e-commerce part where the client wants to sell products online and make deals and coupons and gather some specific type of data such as most selling products and so.

I havent used Magento before and am afraid i wont meet my deadline if i get to learn Magento and try to develop the site in this short period of time (1 month for the first phase of project) thats why i have some questions:

Can I drop some of the running features of Magento such as sales and shopping cart and online payment...etc for the first phase where i need to only make a standard website?

How easy is it to add custom html and custom database tables and view user specif data other than products and pricing (image galleries, UI accordions, social media widgets and integrations...)?

How easy is it to maintain responsive content within the Magento CMS while adding custom modifications?

Thanks alot.

Comment: With Magento, expectations of learning what's necessary to make it function and releasing it on an unsuspecting customer within 1 month is a road leading to substance abuse and insanity... I know, our initial web developers tried doing it and I inherited it. 6 Months to 1 Year if you have no prior experience. Extend it out for another year after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento is a very complex, **e-commerce first** system.

It has a very high learning curve and doesn't offer feature rich content management features (all it has is simple CMS pages and blocks).

For e-commerce, Magento is very good, however it requires a lot of knowledge to work with.  Since you're on a 1-month timeframe with no Magento experience, I would not recommend it.  Go with something you're comfortable with, then work from there.

You can always combine two systems (Wordpress + Magento for example) later on to make a website that has both extensive content management AND e-commerce capabilities.